# Dynamic Imports for JavaScript React Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've got a lot of code that looks like the following:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'; import {createContainer} from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import FoodItemList from '../components/FoodItemList.jsx';

import {FoodItems} from '../../api/FoodItems/FoodItems.js';

const FoodItemListContainer = createContainer(({imageIDFilter}) => {
    const user = Meteor.user()
        ? Meteor.user().username
        : '';
    const query = {
        username: {
            $not: {
                $eq: user
            }
        }
    };
    const foodItems = Meteor.subscribe('foodItems');
    const foodItemList = FoodItems.find(query).fetch()
    const loading = !foodItems.ready();

    return {loading, foodItemList, imageIDFilter, user};

}, FoodItemList);

export default FoodItemListContainer
```

Obviously when I refactor I want to remove some of this boiler plate but I'm not sure how I can do this because I don't see how I can dynamically import the files I need. Is this possible in JS React Meteor?

Comment: You cannot dynamically import files. You can either gather the common code into a factory function that produces it (e.g, a function that receives the collection, the name of the subscription, etc. and returns the container It may or may not save you typing or prevent repetition. Another option is to generate the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do dynamic imports with Meteor as mentioned here [using require](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require), but noticed that it is not recommended to do so because it may cause bugs in your app.

I have done this kind of import a few times and my code still work fine. But I do not recommend you to do it, only if you really need it, it may worth trying

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an article about how to do this and, more importantly, when and why to do this.

https://code.zeroasterisk.com/2017/05/meteor-1-5-bundle-optimization/

TL;DR: `import('./my_component')` returns a promise, which resolves when the client has it.

**before**: normal import part of clientside bundle

```
import PickDates from './PickDates';
```

**after**: dynamic import no longer a part of clientside bundle

```
import Loader from 'react-loader';

// generic loading component to show while transfering section of code
const LoadingComponent = () => <span className="text-muted"><i className="fa fa-refresh" /></span>;
// new version of the component, now: loading --> rendered
const PickDates = Loader({
  // this does the dynamic import, and returns a promise
  loader: () => import('./PickDates'),
  // this is our generic loading display (optional)
  LoadingComponent,
  // this is a delay before we decide to show our LoadingComponent (optional)
  delay: 200,
});
```